# How can I use Cloudflare WARP over SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, wireguard, socks-proxy, cloudflare

I can't find a way to use Cloudflare WARP client over local SOCKS5 proxy.
I even tried using Proxifier to force it to use proxy but it couldn't connect, probably because WARP uses WireGuard, which is UDP, but Proxifier only support TCP.

my local proxy on 127.0.0.1 however supports both TCP and UDP.

so how can I use Cloudflare WARP over my local SOCKS5 proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cloudflare mode to proxy mode, in this case I'm using my linux server, so I don't have a GUI.

First type :

```
warp-cli register
warp-cli set-mode proxy
warp-cli set-proxy-port 4000 // or anything
warp-cli connect
```

In this case I'm using proxychains4 so I need to edit my `proxychains4.conf`.

After that I try to test using:

```
proxychains4 curl wtfismyip.com/json
```

Comment: he wasn't asking how to make warp as local proxy, instead he want to connect warp as gateway vpn through local proxy. So, it's not about `warp -> socks5_by_warp -> internet`. But he wanted to `foreign_socks5 -> warp -> internet`

Answer (score -1):

You can use proxy-mode of warp client, [official doc here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-warp-for-linux-and-proxy-mode/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1186183)